# Difference between fragment caching and wp_cache

Tags: query, cache

I've been really confused about these two caching modes. What's the main difference between fragment caching and wp_cache? Can both of them be used hand in hand?

**EDIT**

I've read about the fragment caching found in the link commented by @Steven. 
I just want to know what's there difference and which one to use for better performance.

Comment: I don't know enough about caching to post an answer, but have you seen this article? https://css-tricks.com/wordpress-fragment-caching-revisited ?

Comment: @Steven, yeah, i did stumble upon that material and it was really helpful. It only explains how fragment caching though. I think i wanted to know the difference between both of them and which one to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll post this as an answer, even though I don't know much about caching.

If you read about [WP Object Cache](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Object_Cache) it says:

> By default, the object cache is non-persistent. This means that data
>   stored in the cache resides in memory only and only for the duration
>   of the request. Cached data will not be stored persistently across
>   page loads unless you install a persistent caching plugin.

From what I understand from the [article by Ryan Burnette](https://css-tricks.com/wordpress-fragment-caching-revisited/), you can set the caching time yourself.

> Fragment caching takes the output of a code block and stores it so for
>   a predetermined amount of time. When the code runs, as long as the
>   time limit hasn't elapsed, the block is ignored and the stored output
>   is returned and printed onto the page.

We'll know soon if I'm completely off the mark here :)

Comment: Okay. @Steven I think that sounds easy to understand. It seems that fragment caching can help a lot with the optimization of the page load. Am i right?

Comment: Definitely. Especially if your query is a bit heavy. You save server request, server load and it saves time because you don't have to fetch the data from the server. I don't use custom cache for simple sites. But you can consider using the plugin `wp-super-cache`.

Comment: Thank you, @Steven. I have this taxonomy page that queries all the post under it and it determines whether the post is a video, a single image or a gallery, and it have a quite complicated logic. You think i can use fragment caching in it?

Comment: You can use caching for any data that is returned. But when it comes to taxonomies, I'm not that technical. Sorry :)

Comment: That's alright. But i guess i can use it to for my wp_query in my taxonomy. Thanks anyway @Steven